# Dividng a word into smaller segments

Tags: c++, suffix-tree

I'm trying to implement a suffix tree.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string text;
    cin >> text;
    int n = text.size();
    std::string first_array[sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0])];

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size();i++)
    {
        first_array[i] = text.substr(i, n - i);
    }

    int T = sizeof(first_array) / sizeof(first_array[0]);
    sort(first_array, first_array + T);

    cout << endl << "The sorted tree:" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(first_array) / sizeof(first_array[0]); j++)
        cout << j+1 << " | " << first_array[j] << endl;
}
```

That is my code. And for example, if the user inputs "hello", then the program **should** and **I want it to** show me this:

```
1 | ello
2 | hello
3 | llo
4 | lo
5 | o
```

But, it is showing me this instead (which is wrong and is **NOT** what I want):

```
1  |
2  |
3  |
4  |
5  |
6  |
7  |
8  |
9  |
10 |
11 |
12 |
13 |
14 |
15 |
16 |
17 |
18 |
19 |
20 |
21 |
22 |
23 |
24 | ello
25 | hello
26 | llo
27 | lo
28 | o
```

Comment: Print the values of `sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0])` for various inputs. (`sizeof` does not do what you think it does.)

Comment: cout << sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]) shows me the value "28".

Comment: you use a std::string. Just use std::string::size() to get the text length

Comment: @suresegul So `first_array` is an array with 28 elements. That *could* be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(std::string)` reports the size of the C++ string object (which is, apparently, 28 bytes large), which has nothing to do with the actual length of the string it contains. Use the `".size()"` member function for the amount of characters contained in the  string and sizing your array.

An alternative would be to use `std::vector<std::string>` and let *it* sort out the memory management:

```
std::vector<std::string> first_array;
for (int i = 0; i < text.size();i++)
         first_array.push_back( text.substr(i, n - i) );
```

For completeness' sake, here's a working program:

```
std::string text;
cout << "Please enter your text: ";
cin >> text;
std::vector<std::string> first_array;

for (int i = 0; i < text.size();i++)
    first_array.push_back( text.substr(i, n - i) );

sort(first_array.begin(), first_array.end());

cout << endl << "Suffix Tree (alphabetical order):" << endl;

std::vector<std::string>::iterator  ptr;
for(ptr=first_array.begin(); p!=first_array.end(); ptr++)
    cout << *ptr;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: std::sort(first_array.begin(), first_array.end()) for in-place sort. See e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: Then you're declaring a C-style array of 20 std::string objects.

Comment: You don't. That's why you use "std::vector" and let the ".push_back()" allocate the elements for you. Then first_array.size() will tell you how many elements there are in the vector, after you're done appending all the suffixes. ["vector" is C++ speak for 'array', for all practical purposes]